# Calculate Sensibility, Specificity, NPV and PPV with different thresholds in R

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

I'm using the following code for the calculation of Sensibility, Specificity, NPV and PPV using **RandomForest** as classifier.

```
   suppressMessages(require(randomForest));
   classifier <- randomForest(x.train,y.train,ntree=300,importance=T)
   prediction <<- predict(classifier,x.test,type="response")

   suppressMessages(require(caret));
   accuracyData <- confusionMatrix(prediction,y.test)
```

In **accuracyData** I have all the information about the prediction quality (sensitivity, specificity, etc.).

Anyway, I'd like to make this calculations for different thresholds, but I don't see how to specify such value in my code.

Comment: what is `x.train`? `y.train`? Please add some sample data

Comment: Just run a vector of candidate 'x.test's through `predict` and plot them versus the predicted response. Sensitivity and specificity are calculated at particular cutpoints , so you may not have as much information as you think you do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you predict a "response", you are making a dichotomous decision and you are losing information about your uncertainty. At that point a threshold has already been applied to make the decision. If you want to try different thresholds, you should output the probability of a response instead. For example

```
#sample data
set.seed(15)
x<- matrix(runif(100,0,5), ncol=1)
y<- 3-2*x[,1] + rnorm(100, 2, 2)
y<- factor(ifelse(y>median(y), "A","B"))

x.train<-x[1:50,, drop=F]
y.train<-y[1:50]

x.test<-x[-(1:50),,drop=F]
y.true<-y[-(1:50)]

#fit the model
library(randomForest)
classifier <- randomForest(x.train,y.train,ntree=500,importance=T)
prediction <- predict(classifier,x.test, type="prob")

#calculate performance
library(pROC)
mroc<-roc(y.true, prediction[,1], plot=T)
```

[image]

And then we can calculate the values of interest for different thresholds

```
coords(mroc, .5, "threshold", ret=c("sensitivity","specificity","ppv","npv"))
# sensitivity specificity         ppv         npv 
#   0.7586207   0.8095238   0.8461538   0.7083333 

coords(mroc, .9, "threshold", ret=c("sensitivity","specificity","ppv","npv"))
# sensitivity specificity         ppv         npv 
#   0.9655172   0.6666667   0.8000000   0.9333333
```